# sqlite sqlalchemy "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

See code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704517/5568923)

**Error Message for `MONTHS = [record.month for record in data[0].city_meteo_data]`**

> /sqlalchemy/orm/util.py", line 1990, in _getitem
> return list(iterable_query[item : item + 1])[0]
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: did also try/catch around **data[0]** which returns the same exception

Comment: I've got it working but with another local sqlite database file....even though they have similar properties that I can see from using Jetbrains Pycharm IDE. If I have anything more to share I will post back on this thread

Answer (score 0):

when you calling the last element in list you get this error

you cant get the last item and one after that

```
iterable_query[item : item + 1]
```

you can limit the loop you are using

Comment: not sure if that helps....have updated mine with where it fails.